# Why is Winforms in Mono not opening any window?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, macos, mono

I'm trying to use Winforms for a simple application on my Mac in Mono C#, so far I've tested this code

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class HelloWorld : Form
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        Application.Run (new HelloWorld ());
    }

    public HelloWorld ()
    {
        Button b = new Button ();
        b.Text = "Click Me!";
        b.Click += new EventHandler (Button_Click);
        Controls.Add (b);
    }

    private void Button_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show ("Button Clicked!");
    }
}
```

But no window is opening when I test it, any help? I think my question is specific to Mono.

Comment: Winforms uses paint calls to gdi32.DLL I believe this might be the issue

Comment: @Sayse, Mono's WinForms does not rely on gdi32 but libgdiplus. That makes WinForms apps portable to other platforms than Windows.

Comment: You'd better launch it from a command prompt/terminal and see if there is any exception thrown.

Comment: Also, make sure you have the latest Mono framework installed. Mono WinForms didn't work well in the 2.x versions but seems to work fine in 3.1

Answer (score 7):

i have the same issue, running os x mavericks + mono 3.2.3 .

i built the demos from here : http://mono-project.com/Mono_Basics , the first two worked (console+gtk) but the third (dotnet) does nothing when i run it from Terminal, doesn't throw any error, i only makes cpu load, but no window is shown...

in the end , i found the solution, **on the first dotnet run, it takes about 1 minute until the window shows**, on the next run it's instant. when i was testing, i was killing the process after 5-10 seconds, so that's why i didn't worked for me on first try...

Comment: Same issue, after reinstalling mono on os x - when i try running winform sample application (create basic winform project in visual studio on windows and open in xamarin) no form showing and no exception. Waiting about 30sek and form shows, after that all winform project work instantly. Maybe first run compile some mono dependencies, i didn't find information about it?

Comment: Does anyone know what mono is doing during that first 1 minute? Subsequent runs seems faster. I was guessing it is pre-JIT-ing the DLLs, but the [doc](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/) says this is only on OS X though, so I wonder why the behaviour.

Comment: This is still an issue for me too in mono 5.8 -.-

Comment: I also confirm that patience is a virtue and needed to wait well over 60 seconds for a WinForms application to come up on my MacOs with mono 5.18.0.225 installed with brew. Once it finally did, all other WinForms applications launched immediately. I also needed to do `mono --arch=32 MyApp.exe` if that helps anyone.

Comment: Confirmed. Need to wait 60+ seconds when window will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Not with Mono but with WinForms. For me the solution was:

1. Remove *bin* and *obj* directories from WinForms project.
2. Remove *.vs* directory (I was using Visual Studio).

Those above helped me. Of course I had to input any setting again, but at least I could use the application again.